# Bot assigns user a role, even if user doesn't own role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, quick.db

Sorry for the confusing title, I'll clarify. I'm trying to make the bot check if a user has a certain role in their quick.db inventory, and if they do, it'll equip that role. The problem I'm having is that even with the role in the inventory, it returns the error that the role isn't owned. I have a feeling that the problem is the `if (db.has(message.author.id + '.hot rod red'))` line, as I'm not too sure how to format checking for a role with quick.db. Sorry for the messy code, if anyone knows how to fix this let me know, thanks!

```
if (db.has(message.author.id + '.hot rod red')) {
  if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'hot rod red')) {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription('You already have this role equipped!');
    return message.channel.send(embed);
  } else {
       await message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('733373020491481219');

       let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription(`You now have the ${message.guild.roles.cache.get('733373020491481219')} role!`);
       message.channel.send(embed);
       user.roles.remove(user.roles.highest);
  }
} else {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription('You do not own this role!'); // ERROR HERE; GIVES ROLE EVEN WITHOUT OWNING
    return message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: try `console.log(db.get(message.author.id + '.hot rod red'))` to check if the user actually has the role

Comment: Doesn't look like that worked, it still returns the same thing, but now in the console, it returns false. Could it have something to do with the formatting of .hot rod red? It's a role, so it shows in the inventory as "@hot rod red"

Answer (score 1):

Probably try something like
`let check = db.get(message.author.id+'.hot rod red')`
and check if it is true/false, I'd say to use string rather then boolean as you can use `if(check === 'false/true'){}`. You can also do

```
if(!check || check === 'false'){ return 
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription('You do not own this role!');
return message.channel.send(embed);
 }
```

So the final code would be:

```js
let check = await db.get(message.author.id + '.hot rod red');
let rejectEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription('You do not own this role!');

if(!check){
return message.channel.send(rejectEmbed) 
}
if(check === 'true'){
if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'hot rod red')) {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription('You already have this role!');
    return message.channel.send(embed);
  } else {
       await message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('733373020491481219');

       let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription(`You now have the ${message.guild.roles.cache.get('733373020491481219')} role!`);
       message.channel.send(embed);
       user.roles.remove(user.roles.highest); // I'm unsure why this is here, this could be causing a potential error
  }
}
```

If there are any more questions, please comment!! I hope this has helped.

Comment: Thank you so much for the in depth response! I tried out that solution, and it's for some reason still giving the same ```('You do not own this role!')``` response, I tried retyping everything, but still no luck. Could it be because the role name in ```let check = await db.get(message.author.id + '.hot rod red');``` line is formatted wrong, resulting in the bot being unable to find that role? (The last line is to remove the current highest role, so that when the user equips a new role, their current color role is removed so it doesn't overrun it)